# MongoDb RunCommand to query embedded array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to use "db.RunCommand" to get an item from an array embedded into a collection. I am just starting MongoDB and I am having difficulty looking into the MongoDB documentation since i can't find much examples using **directly** the "RunCommand" method.

So if i have this example

```
[
   {
     "Brand": {
         "Name": "Brand name 1",
         "Products": [
            {
                 "Product":  "Product 1",
                 "Price": 20.33
            },
             // i need to get only the following object
            { 
                 "Product":  "Product 2",
                 "Price": 10.33
            },
            {
                 "Product":  "Product 2",
                 "Price": 15.33
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

So how can i construct the query into the "RunCommand(--query here--)" to get only "Product 2" ?
So the result would be

```
{ 
   "Product":  "Product 2",
   "Price": 10.33
}
```

If is needed, i am using C# .net Core with MongoDB Driver

Answer (score 1):

```
db.runCommand({
    aggregate: "your_collection",
    "pipeline": [
        {$match: {"_id": ObjectId("5fcd2d3b08c6590a0cd04630")}},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0, "products": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$a.Brand.Products", 0]}}}, 
        {$project: {"products": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$products", 1]}}}],
    cursor: {}})
```